# Is it possible for a hostname to be associated to a webserver and a DNS server?

Tags: networking, dns

I've been studying computer networking in this summer, and i can't seem to find anything (or maybe i found the answer but i didn't understand it as it) that can provide as a definitive answer for the question. I know a hostname points to a machine at an end-point, and the DNS resolves the hostname into an IP address and then if the local DNS server doesn't have it in cache, then it starts the "journey" through the DNS servers of the different levels...i'm soory for the long post, i'm new in here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. A server can support multiple services all on the same machine, but they will be running on different ports. If hat doesn't answer your question you need to clarify it.

Comment: No, it was just that, thanks David! I wasn't sure of the answer and i wasn't able to find in my notes anything that could provide a direct answer! Living and learning. Thanks again!

Comment: Just to clear up a bit of mystery, a hostname is not the same as a domainname. DNS only translates domain names into ipadresses. A hostname is broadcasted by the machine itself across the network, and that's how other machines on the network find it.

Comment: That's an important distinction. Thanks for the clarification!